# Batch script that should only delete 0 byte files is deleting non 0 byte files and also in subfolders even without /s

Tags: batch-file, del, forfiles

I have a pretty simple .bat script to cleanup 0 byte files on a folder:

```
@echo off
FORFILES /P "E:\Path" /C "CMD /C IF @FSIZE==0 del @FILE /Q"
```

The problem is, it's deleting files that are NOT 0 bytes and also deleting all files in the subfolders as well, even though I'm not using the /S switch.

Comment: You are not using the `/S` option so there is no way your code is deleting files in sub-folders.

Comment: Also the `@FILE` variable does not include the file path so it will try to delete the file in the current working directory and not necessarily in `E:\Path`.  So you need to use the `@path` variable to delete the file.

Comment: @Squashman I don't know what to tell you, it is most definitely deleting files in the subfolder, even when I used `@PATH` instead of `@FILE`. I have tested is several times, including just now, just to verify.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `for`:

```
@echo off
for /r %%A in (*.*) do if %%~zA==0 del "%%~fA" /q
```

With that, you are looping for every file in directories and subdirectories, and getting its size with `%%~zvar` (In this case `%%~zA`).

Then, using an `if` to see if the size is equal to 0 bytes. If it is, it will delete the empty file.

Comment: I _don't_ want to delete any files in the subfolders, just the folder(s) I specify.

Comment: Remove the /R switch.

Comment: well at least it's not deleting stuff in sub-folders. I still have no idea why it doesn't delete my 0 byte files though. Interestingly, I get the following message when I try to run in CMD: <path> "was unexpected at this time."

Comment: Thank you for the great answer.  It's a much better answer than the other ridiculously complicated answer.

Comment: The only change I think this may need is enquoting the second `%%A`  so it handles pathnames that contain one or more spaces.  What do you think?

Comment: Alright thanks, I've already updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) method, which uses [robocopy](/questions/tagged/robocopy) and [findstr](/questions/tagged/findstr), to select the 0 byte files as the `In` command. I find it more efficient to select all the files within that block instead filtering everything one by one in the `Do` portion.

If you're only deleting those in the top level directory itself:

```batch-file
@For /F Tokens^=1* %%G In ('^""%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" "E:\Path" NULL /L /NC /NDL /NJH /NJS^|"%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /RC:"^[\   \ ]*0[\ ]"^"')Do @Del /A/F "%%H"
```

Or, if you were wanting to delete those in the subdirectories, just add the `/S` option in your `Robocopy.exe` command:

```batch-file
@For /F Tokens^=1* %%G In ('^""%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" "E:\Path" NULL /L /NC /NDL /NJH /NJS /S^|"%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /RC:"^[\    \ ]*0[\ ]"^"')Do @Del /A/F "%%H"
```

Just to ensure the board formatting doesn't corrupt the above examples, the [findstr](/questions/tagged/findstr) match is supposed to be:
<kbd>^</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>

Comment: This is not working. Is there something else besides the target path I need to change?

Comment: What I posted is a complete batch file. In order to test my code, @OatMaGoat, you must create a new batch file, containing only what I've posted, nothing else added, removed or modified other than `E:\Path` _(the doublequotes should still enclose it afterwards!)_. And I know the code works, I have been using it for more years than I'd care to admit to...

Comment: That is exactly what I did; I created a new file with a .bat extension, edited it with NPP, and changed _only_ the `E:\Path` part. There must be something else going on because I also couldn't get `for` with `del` to work properly either, despite me literally copying and pasting it, changing only the path, saving it as a *.bat, and running it, with nothing happening at all. Appreciate your response; I ultimately found what I need with a PS1 script.

Comment: Did you specifically check that the site software has not modified the code, and ensured that it matches the layout I provided at the foot of my answer? Also If you change it to `@(For /F Tokens^=1* %%G In ('^""%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" "E:\Path" NULL /L /NC /NDL /NJH /NJS^|"%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /RC:"^[\ \ ]*0[\ ]"^"')Do @Echo [%%G] "%%H")&Pause`, it should show you the files size followed by its name. e.g. [0] "filename.ext" If that outputs correctly, perhaps you've got a stupid issue, like an executable file named `Del`, which is taking over the internal command `Del`.

Answer (score 0):

For example. Clear only empty file in directory "log"

```
:: Clear empty logs
FOR %%F IN (".\log\*") DO (
 IF %%~zF LSS 1 DEL /Q "%%F"
)
```